# ul list in PHP not working properly

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to get some help with what's going on in my code. I have tried a lot of variations but can't make it work.

It's a ul-list in a PHP-code. It's inlined styled in CSS and everything else is fine, but somehow the ul-list aligns with one of the if-elseif-else-statements (url, slug or id) and I can't figure out why.
I've tried a lot of variations with putting `</li>` and `</li></ul>` in the end of the if-else-statements but neither do that work.

```
$parts = array();    
    foreach ($content AS $id => $val){      
        $position = "<li>";
        $position.="<h2><a href='post.php?id='" . $val->id . "'>" . $val->title . "</a></h2>";
        $position.="<h6>" . $val->published . "</h6>";
        $position.="<p>" . substr($val->data, 0, 100) . "...";          

        if ($val->url){ 
            $position .= "<a href='post.php?url={$val->url}'><span class='small red'>Läs mer</span></a>"; 
        } 
        elseif ($val->slug){ 
            $position .= "<a href='post.php?slug={$val->slug}'><span class='small red'>Läs mer</span></a>"; 
        } 
        else { 
            $position .= "<a href='post.php?id={$val->id}'><span class='small red'>Läs mer</span></a>"; 
        }
        $position .= "</p></li>"; 
        $parts[] = $position;
    }       
    $htmltext = "<ul class='latest-news'>" . implode('', $parts) . "</ul>";
```

Could it be something with CSS?

```
ul.latest-news {
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
float: none;
margin-top: 0px;
position: relative;
display: inline;
}

ul.latest-news li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 0 1em;
margin: 1.5em 0.6em;
max-width: 28%;
min-width: 250px;
height: 185px;
border: thin solid #C8C3C3;
border-radius: 21px;
}
```

![enter image description here][2]

[image: Dump]

Comment: where do you close your tag `<p>` ?

Comment: I updated the code, but problem remains... Could it be in CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close your `<p>` tag, **and also open single quote in `id=` param**. Here you go:

```
$parts = array();
foreach ($content AS $id => $val) {
    $position = "<li>";

    //don't mix string concatenation methods, it makes things harder to read
    $position.="<h2><a href='post.php?id='" . $val->id . "'>" . $val->title . "</a></h2>";

    $position.="<h6>" . $val->published . "</h6>";
    $position.="<p>" . substr($val->data, 0, 70) . "...";

    if ($val->url) {
        $position.="<a href='post.php?url={$val->url}'><span class='small red'>Läs mer</span></a>";
    } elseif ($val->slug) {
        $position.="<a href='post.php?slug={$val->slug}'><span class='small red'>Läs mer</span></a>";
    } else {
        $position.="<a href='post.php?id={$val->id}'><span class='small red'>Läs mer</span></a>";
    }
    $position .= "</p></li>"; //<p> closed
    $parts[] = $position;
}

$htmltext = "<ul class='latest-news'>" . implode('', $parts) . "</ul>";
```

To check if html is generated correctly:

```
echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($htmltext);
echo "</pre>";
die();
```

Comment: Your code looks much better but problem still remains. Ul aligns with "Läs mer" in all my inline-posts. Could it be something with the CSS?
I have updated my code above.

Comment: Could you post example HTML output and add it to question? Use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: It's too complicated - it's a method from a class and I get the HTML from another class, but I took a screenshot of the structure where you can see it and how it aligns with the red small text beneath.(the long red line is only for clearence)

Comment: Firebug and other extensions tend to repair broken html. It's not that hard to output html from your code. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: I've put a picture of the result from the dump. Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 2):

`$htmltext .= "</li>";`

change to:

`$htmltext .= "</p></li>";`